# Select parameter with less than PHP PDO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
if ($stmt - > execute()) {
    if ($stmt - > rowCount() > 0) {
        $menu_id = array();
        while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $menu_id[] = array('menuid' => $selected_row['menulist_id'], );
        }
        $stmt = $dbh - > prepare("SELECT * FROM menulist_tbl WHERE menulist_id = :menuid AND menu_displayorder <= :value");
        $menu_name = array();
        $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $menu_id)));
        //print_r($menu_id);
        //print_r($input);
        foreach($input as $row) {
            $stmt - > execute(array(':menuid' => $row['menuid'], ':value' => '10000'));
            //while ($selected_row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)){
            while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $menu_name[] = array('displayorder' => $selected_row['menu_displayorder'], 'menuname' => $selected_row['menu_name'], 'menuurl' => $selected_row['menu_url'], 'menuflag' => $selected_row['menu_flag'], 'menuid' => $selected_row['menulist_id']);
            }
        }
        array_multisort($menu_name);
        //print_r($menu_name);
        return $menu_name;
    }
}
```

This is how i get menu from database this code will do the following:

From result of another query it will store in an array the `menulist_id` then I will use this `menulist_id` to query the menu table for menu name that has a display order of `less 10000` , I have this parameter of `less than 10000` because i can hide menu from the list of menu without deleting them so I want to show them again I just reduce their display order and they can be seen again. But why is my display order parameter not working even if i have a display order of `10011` the menu is still showing. Any idea is appreciated

`FYI`

the column menu_displayorder is varchar.

Answer (score 0):

For a varchar you will want to `CAST` as a numerical data type that can controlled better with `>=` try this:

```
AND CAST(menu_displayorder AS UNSIGNED) <= :value
```